# Convert String into Blob

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm new to JDBC and stack overflow as well, and what I'm trying to do here is this :

I'm trying to insert a string as blob into a database but I'm getting null pointer exception. Here is the code I'm using :

```
public String execute() {
    String success="Success";
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://panorama-pc:3306/sample", "sample", "sample123");
        String sql = "Insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setNull(1, Types.NULL);  
        ps.setString(2,name);
        ps.setString(3,RollNo);
        ps.setString(4, date);

        Blob blob = con.createBlob();

        blob.setBytes(1,desc.getBytes()); // getting exception here 

        int i = ps.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0){
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        else{
            return ERROR;
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here desc is a string and I'm trying to insert it into a blob column. Can someone please help me out ?

Comment: *Where* are you getting the exception? (Note that using the parameterless `String.getBytes()` is usually a bad idea - specify the encoding, e.g. UTF-8. Also, having a return value for success/error isn't idiomatic Java - usually you'd throw an exception for errors...)

Comment: Near blob.setBytes only..

Comment: Might `desc` be null?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : No its not, I declared it outside the execute method.

Comment: Lol @DB instance, username and password in clear :D

Comment: @AndreaLigios : That doesn't matter now

Comment: @Karthik I guess those are useless, test-only credentials, but it's unsafe the same to post them (eg if you use them elsewhere, or if a pattern can be evinced...). Did you know ? By clicking on the "edited XX mins ago" link you can see the previous versions of the post. They won't go away. Never. Never Ever. Just be careful :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios : Okay Bro.. sure

Answer (score 1):

A few possible problems:

- It's not clear why you're explicitly setting a parameter to null. Why not just specify the column names explicitly in the SQL (which will make it clearer) and omit that column/parameter?
- Although you're creating the blob, you're never using it as a parameter in your statement. You need `ps.setBlob(...)` somewhere
- Your call to `String.getBytes` doesn't specify a `Charset`; I would strongly advise you to do so
- You're not closing either the connection or the statement. Ideally, do so with a try-with-resources statement

For the `NullPointerException`... you haven't said where the exception occurs, but if `desc` is `null`, that would explain it - consider what you want your blob to contain in that case (or whether you should set the parameter to null).

Comment: [`Blob.setBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#setBytes-long-byte:A-) first position is **1**, like most indexes in JDBC (and the SQL standard) they are 1-based.

Comment: I'm setting it null because it is an auto increment column set with a default value. So that is not the problem

Comment: @Karthik You should instead explicitly specify the columns to insert to, and leave the rest out.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thanks, will remove that point... I thought I'd checked the docs, but apparently not :(